# Passing func from method parameter into a LINQ method (generic types)

Tags: c#, linq, generics

In the signature of a method I specify a Func, like so:

```
public void Method (Func<string, bool> func)
```

In LINQ, which method (from IEnumerable) will let me pass in a Func from the method parameter to the LINQ query? The other issue is, my func can have any type parameter(s) so the Method from IEnumerable/LINQ must support generic type placeholders.

I want to write something like this:

```
// Get all elements of type T from the webpage (find is an object in an external API to look for elements in a page).

IEnumerable<T> images = find.GetAllByTagName<T>().All(func);

// Where func is a method parameter which is assigned at run time by the consumer of this API:

public void Test (Func<T, bool> func) { }
```

How can I best do this? I am on .NET 3.5

Thanks

Comment: You know the return type of .All() is a boolean, not an IEnumerable, right?  You probably want .Where() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In LINQ, which method (from IEnumerable) will let me pass in a Func from the method parameter to the LINQ query?

The extension methods for LinqToObjects hang out on the static [System.Linq.Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx) class.

---

Given your Func signature, you probably want [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) overload of `Enumerable.Where`.

`IEnumerable<T> Enumerable.Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter)`

Comment: Yep. I saw where but didn't notice the overload (I don't need int). That's why I had the problem at first.

Answer (score 1):

Change your API's signature to be open:

```
public void Method<T> (Predicate<T> func)
```

Your consumer would close the generic signature with a type T, and supply an appropriate Predicate.

The actual method implementation using LINQ would use Joel's aforementioned Where()

**Edit:** changed func to predicate

**Additional Edit:**

I'd personally return an IEnumerable representing your result set constrained by the predicate passed in:

```
public IEnumerable Method<T> (Predicate<T> func)
{
    return find.Where(func)
}
```

I'm making some assumptions of what you're trying to do, let me know if this is your intent.

Comment: Predicate won't fit in a Where clause, no conversion between Predicate<T> and Func<T, bool>. You could, however, put thePredicate.Invoke inside the Where clause. It will get converted to a Func<T, bool>.

Comment: Interesting, thanks Judah.  I thought it'd be a safe assumption that it would work as an implicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

> In LINQ, which method (from
>   IEnumerable) will let me pass in a
>   Func from the method parameter to the
>   LINQ query?

That question is a little fuzzy to me. If you're looking for a filter algorithm that returns only the matches specified by the Func, use the .Where method:

```
public void Method (Func<string, bool> func)
{
    return find.GetAllByTagName<T>().Where(func);
}
```

Does that answer your question? If not, please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: I will give this a go when I get on my work machine. I think I rushed the coding due to external pressures (no fault other than mine).